# Networking in Linux based OS

Tags: networking

Last month our computers were hit by a *ransomware*.

After this event, we have been advised to move all of our computers to any Linux based OS and we have decided to go with Ubuntu.

The following are our doubts.

- Will our network need any modifications in order to change OS?.
- Will we need to notify our ISP about this change?.

Comment: I can perfectly understand a not computer savvy individual being hit by ransomware (and all sorts of malware/virus) but TBH, in a company that's unacceptable regardless of the OS. It's "exhibit A" of a pile of bad practices that if continued in Ubuntu will result in the same or similar problems. Please pay special attention to Pilot6's last paragraph.

Comment: Actually Linux is real magical they use seperate protocols communicate wirelessly to the next linux computer in the area and once enough linux systems get together they form a bond called cluster to communicate even faster and even further. Once your ISP notices that you might be in trouble since you could just cancle your subscription to them since you will be already networking with most people via those special network protocols.... *Irony off* But seriously now that's why RFC's exist.

Answer (score 6):

Generally networking on Linux is the same as on Windows.

But it depends on whether you are using any Microsoft specific network services. Most of them can be used with Linux too.

Regarding the ISP, it does not make any difference for ISP which OS are you using unless they are using something very specific.

The more important thing to think about is to get a Linux literate admin for your network.